# Ruby on Rails - Make Slim the Default Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, slim-lang

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project and am needing to customize default views provided by Gems.

The requirement is to use Slim for template. I understand that ERB is the default template engine for Rails.

As per my observation, the priority is for ERB and if not it will use Slim/Haml views.

I am interested in knowing if it is possible to set Slim as the default instead of the ERB?

How can this be achieved so that when I create a local version of a template in Slim it will override the template provided by the gem.

Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use "slim-rails" gem which is built for generating slim template as default.

https://github.com/slim-template/slim-rails

Just replace `gem 'slim'` by `gem 'slim-rails'` in your Gemfile.

Comment: Is there a way to add slim within `rails new MyProject`?

Comment: @Basi, when generating new project, there is no view so I don't think you need it. Also there is no Gemfile for adding the gem.

Comment: You're right. However there is application.html.erb. But this is easy to change. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Besi you could achieve this with application templates - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html

Comment: what's the difference between "slim" and "slim-rails"?

Comment: @アレックス It looks like "slim-rails" has "slim" has a dependency, but has additional code for configuring Rails generators.

Answer (score 26):

In you Gemfile, include

```
gem 'slim-rails'
```

And to generate slim tempage, in config/application.rb add this line of code

```
class Application < Rails::Application
........................................

    config.generators do |g|
      g.template_engine :slim
    end
end
```

Comment: what's the difference between "slim" and "slim-rails"?

Comment: @アレックス slim-rails for rails generates

Comment: This got `rails generate controller` to generate slims instead of erbs, but how do I tell Puma to looks for slims instead of erbs?